# ¿Cómo hacer una validación de un registro en SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

Quiero realizar una validación de un login usando xamarin.forms con SQLite, al momento de que yo registre algo en mi tabla "usuarios", y tenga datos como nombre, apellidos, correo y contraseña y, posteriormente quiera "iniciar sesion", si dicho correo y contraseña se encuentran en la tabla "usuarios" que se me permita acceder y se muestren los respectivos datos de ese registro...
Solo he intentado una sentencia para que se muestren los datos:

```
public static IEnumerable<Usuario> SELECT_WHERE (SQLiteConnection db, int id)
        {
            return db.Query<Usuario>("SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Id_usuario=?", id);
        }
```

Pero estoy algo perdido con la situación del Login...¿Que puedo hacer?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No entiendo tu problema.. en lugar de buscar por id, buscas por usuario y contraseña... cual seria el problema?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.